# How to create temp table in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm getting syntax errors when trying to create a temp table in BigQuery.

```
CREATE TABLE sleep_day select distinct *
FROM `<project>.<dataset>.sleepDay`
```

I tried to duplicate the entire dataset so I can drop duplicated values in the new table while keeping the original but not working for me as well.

```
SELECT * INTO sleep_day
FROM `<project>.<dataset>.sleepDay`
```

My goal is to remove duplicated values without losing the original data. I want to be able to go back to the original data if I need to.

Comment: Please tag which database you are using. It will be helpful if you mention data volume also.

Answer (score -1):

Seams you show use a table that expires instead of a temp table.
Take in mind one thing:

> Temporary tables let you save intermediate results to a table. These temporary tables exist at the session level, so you don't need to save or maintain them in a dataset. They are automatically deleted some time after the script completes.

It means you have to use it inside a script or session. Maybe its not what you need, as your table data may die some time after the script be executed. A table if expiration of some days may fit better for you

You can use the following query to crate a table that will expire in 3 days.

```sql
CREATE TABLE 
   `<project>.<dataset>.<temp_table_name>`
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
) AS
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<original_table>`
```

To load back the lines from the temp table to the original one do like:

```sql
INSERT INTO `<project>.<dataset>.<original_table>`
    (field1, field2, ...)
SELECT 
    (field1, field2, ...)
FROM 
   `<project>.<dataset>.<temp_table_name>`
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great!